# Storing a record locator in the user's Address Book kABPersonInstantMessageProperty field

Tags: iphone, sdk, contacts, addressbook, abaddressbook

I have an app that uses the user's Address Book for contacts.  I also have other information I wish to store on a per-user basis (per Address Book entry basis).  I allow the user to import a single user, an Address Book group, or all of their contacts.  Because I wish to continue to allow outside applications to change the users Address Book, I do not import all the information.  Instead I have chosen to alter the Address Book entry for each imported user, adding a `kABPersonInstantMessageProperty` key.  I want populate to this key with `MyAppsRecordLocaterNumber@MyAppsDomain.com` as the username.  I figured this will immediately be seen by the end user as both `a:` unobtrusive, and `b:` a link to my app's info (hooking the outside contact info with the internal info my app adds and keeps).  The only problem?  I have NO idea how to add an entry to the `kABPersonInstantMessageProperty` key.  I have figured out how to add multi-value entries such as "Home Address" but when searching stack overflow, I come up with 4 (ONLY FOUR!) entries on questions regarding this key (`kABPersonInstantMessageProperty`).

A portion of my code for adding "Home Address" to a person's Address Book entry is below and I admit that I have no idea how to change this over to kABPersonInstantMessageProperty.

```
 ABMutableMultiValueRef address = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType);  
 NSMutableDictionary *addressDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

 NSMutableString *street = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i];
 [street appendString:@" Main Street"];

 [addressDict setObject:[NSString stringWithString:street] forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];       
 [addressDict setObject:@"San Jose" forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey]; 
 [addressDict setObject:@"CA" forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStateKey]; 

 NSMutableString *zip = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"95"];
 [zip appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%00i",i]];

 [addressDict setObject:zip forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey];      
 ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(address, addressDict, kABHomeLabel, NULL);
 ABRecordSetValue(record, kABPersonAddressProperty, address, NULL); 

 // add the record
 ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, record, NULL);
```

Can someone help?  I would appreciate it.

Comment: Dont you hate it when people downvote a question and don't say why? I logged in almost 1 year after my question was asked (and answered) by myself...and someone downvoted this question 3 days ago!  hrumph!  Downvoters should be listed in comments so we can validate why we asked it.  This question had code and a valid reason for asking it.  Wondering what problem anyone could have with it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GOT IT!

This is so simple!  Thanks to [link text](http://tumblr.caseyliss.com/post/530887744) who had the same issue with lack of Google-able answers on this one.  Thanks, Casey!

Whereas `record` is the ABPerson record and all the `ABCreate` stuff has already been done and `i` is the sequential record locator integer...

```
        ABMutableMultiValueRef im = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType);
        NSMutableDictionary *imDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [imDict setObject:@"MyAppName"  forKey:(NSString*)kABPersonInstantMessageServiceKey];

        NSMutableString *iMID = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i];
        [iMID appendString:@"RL@MyAppDomain"];

        [imDict setObject:iMID forKey:(NSString*)kABPersonInstantMessageUsernameKey];
        ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(im, imDict, kABHomeLabel, NULL);
        [imDict release];
        ABRecordSetValue(record, kABPersonInstantMessageProperty, im, NULL);
```